# Saving multiple tabs in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a couple of "tabs" of photoshop running. How do I save all these tabs into one single "project file" so that when I open this "project file", it would open all of the "tabs" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save them all into one file but you can record an action to save all the open documents. You can go here for more information on making actions:

> http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WS262DC4FE-2F31-4e62-A39A-80CD90530422.html